# Spring boot @Value not working for static field

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I am trying to get value from a property file on spring boot. 
**application.properties** file is under resources folder, and its content;

```
TEST=someText
```

And the code is;

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;

@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")

public class Bb8Application {


    @Value("${TEST}")
    static String someString;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.print(someString);

    }

}
```

I get NULL as a result instead of "someText". Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring: How to inject a value to static field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253694/spring-how-to-inject-a-value-to-static-field)

Comment: Did you make sure that the `application.properties` file is actually present on the classpath, i.e. it is bundled with the JAR when you execute it?

Answer (score 7):

Spring does not allow injecting to static fields. If you really want to use static variable you can try this [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253694/spring-how-to-inject-a-value-to-static-field).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Value` annotation for static fields.

```
@Component
public class MyClass {

   private static String MY_STATIC_FIELD;

   public MyClass(@Value("${TEST}") String input) {
      MY_STATIC_FIELD = input;
   }

}
```

more for information: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-inject-static-field