# Reading properties from Application.properties in Spring Boot REST application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I am trying to access a custom property from application.properties (present in src/main/resources) of my Spring Boot rest application and trying to access that value from my controller

Spring boot application class location "src/main/java/com/myapp/FileReaderApp.java"

```
package com.myapp;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class FileReaderApp {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(FileReaderApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

Controller class location : "src/main/java/com/myapp/controller/FileReaderController.java"

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/counter-api")
public class FileReadController {

    @Value("${fileLocation}")
    static private String fileLocation;
    //do other actions 
   }
```

I found out i couldnt do it at all and everytime fileLocation is coming as null.

My application.properties file has only one property, fileLocation.

Could anyone please advise where I am going wrong in this case and what is the best way to access an application property value in REST Controller class?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253694/spring-how-to-inject-a-value-to-static-field

Comment: @iamiddy the link you provided is similar but didnt help in solving my problem. do you have any other option in mind?

Comment: thought your issue is caused by a static variable?

Comment: Just tried with the following code as well, it didnt help :( it would be great if someone can help                    "@RestController
@RequestMapping("/counter-api")
public class FileReadController {
 
 @Autowired
 private Environment environment;
 
 private FileReaderService service = new FileReaderServiceImpl(environment.getProperty("fileLocation"));"

Comment: are you able to autowire any property value?

Comment: @iamiddy yes tried the above, didnt work

Comment: @Value("${fileLocation}") private String fileLocation;

Comment: No @iamiddy didnt work sorry :( where do you think i should put that in?

Comment: @ManishaB Could you please share the application.properties file content?

Comment: @RavindraDevadiga fileLocation=/Users/mymachine/Documents/workspace/TestStreamsJava8/src/main/resources/file/input.txt

Comment: I just created a quick spring-boot app from start.spring.io and added your controller with the fileLocation property and it worked fine. Only difference was `static`; my variable isn't static. You're code looks fine. It has to be something you're not showing us.

Comment: @Gregg thanks! can you check if you are able to access that variable "fileLocation" , i.e the value is not populated as null?

Comment: Pretty sure that's what I just said; yes, I can access the variable and see it's value, print it, whatever.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring: How to inject a value to static field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253694/spring-how-to-inject-a-value-to-static-field)

Answer (score 3):

You're injecting into a `static` field. This is not supported.