# @Value static anotation is null in the @PostConstruct execution

Tags: java, spring-boot, static, postconstruct

I am facing this problem: I have a class with a @Value variable declared as static as it is shown. When my application starts the @PostConstruct execution access to a method of this class find my variable with a null value.

If I call to this class after de @PostConstruct execution I can see that the @Value static variable is not null and it has the correct value.

How could I have this variable with its real value in the @PostConstruct execution?

This is my code:

```
@Component
public class ValidacionesUtils {

public static String variable;

@Value("${access.to.my.variable}")
public void setVariable(String variable) {
    this.variable = variable;
}

@PostConstruct
private void init() {
    if (variable==null) {
        log.error("This is what my application prints");
    } else {
        log.error("This is not printed");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: try changing the body of your setter to `ValidacionesUtils.variable = variable`

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253694/spring-how-to-inject-a-value-to-static-field

Comment: Send it in through the constructor.

Comment: It doesn't works @michalk

Answer (score 0):

Why are you declaring it public and static?

try doing

```
@Value("${access.to.my.variable}")
private String variable;
```

This should be available in @PostConstruct this way