# Spring boot- Injecting values from spring properties- NullPointer

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a class

```
 public class Constants {
@Value("${graph.apiSecret")
public static   String API_SECRET;
}
```

In my `application-dev.properties` is  `graph.apiSecret=secretHere` property

My test shows API_SECRET as null

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class GraphViewSiteTest {
    @Test
    public void testgetAllFilesInAFolderOnOurDevSite() throws  ConnectException, IOException, OAuth2AccessTokenErrorResponse, InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        System.out.println(Constants.API_SECRET);
   }
```

I am using spring boot 1.5.2

Comment: we’ll first need to define a @PropertySource in our configuration class – with the properties file name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring: How to inject a value to static field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253694/spring-how-to-inject-a-value-to-static-field)

Comment: Use nonstatic setter... 
If you are reading anyway from configuration, be as well use @ Configuration bean instead of static member in constants.  

Note : You also missed ending "}"  in Value annotation @ Value

Answer (score 1):

Spring doesn't inject values into static variables, therefore you have to create a non static setter for it:

```
@Value("${graph.apiSecret]")
public void setApiSecret(String apiSecret){
  API_SECRET= apiSecret;
}
```

Comment: Note : You also missed ending "}" in Value annotation @ Value

Comment: Thanks my bad - just copied it :)

Comment: does that mean I have to instantiate  the class Constants to access it?

Comment: Well I would prefer to get rid of the static variables and add it as @Component so you can autowire it.

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are true you will have to use non static setter.

```
https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-inject-a-value-into-static-variables/
```

But you also need to specify properties file path from where it will read.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Constants.class)
@TestPropertySource("classpath:application-test.properties")  
public class GraphViewSiteTest {

@Test
public void testgetAllFilesInAFolderOnOurDevSite()   {
    System.out.println(Constants.API_SECRET);
   }
}
```