# Not Able to use @value inside @bean in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-cloud-feign

**Hi am using spring 2.4 version and feign cloud from spring cloud**

but i getting stuck that am not able to use some constant value inside `@bean` method  when i reading from property  file

```
@Configuration
public class FeignClientConfiguration {

    @Value("${app.basic.auth.username}")
    private static String userName;

    @Value("${app.basic.auth.password}")
    private static String password;


    @Bean
    public BasicAuthRequestInterceptor basicAuthRequestInterceptor() {
        // return new BasicAuthRequestInterceptor("admin", "admin");
        return new BasicAuthRequestInterceptor(userName, password);
    }
}
```

But i while provides value in like this i will work fine

```
return new BasicAuthRequestInterceptor("admin", "admin");
```

Am not sure why this is not working  can you please suggest me any way to achieve this

Comment: Try `public BasicAuthRequestInterceptor basicAuthRequestInterceptor(@Value("${...}") String username, ....) {`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring: How to inject a value to static field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253694/spring-how-to-inject-a-value-to-static-field)

Comment: i try that also but not working

Comment: @ErvinSzilagyi I also tryed that but not working

Comment: Check you configuration file to make sure it's correct. Also, since `FeignClientConfiguration` is singleton and the members are`private`, I see no reason why should they be `static` and `non-final`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should seperate your configuration class and the basicAuthRequestInterceptor method.

```
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;

@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app")    
public class LoginProperties {

    private String username;
    private String password;    
}
```

In your properties file,have the below:

```
app.username = user
app.password = 123
```

Then in your controller/service class, do the following.

```
@Autowired
private LoginProperties loginProperties; 

public BasicAuthRequestInterceptor basicAuthRequestInterceptor() {
        return new BasicAuthRequestInterceptor(loginProperties.getUserName(), loginProperties.password());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to find out is create a simple **@PostConstruct** method and print both the values..if they are `null` then that means the spring was not able to resolve those property values.

Make sure you've initialized the properties using **[PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html)** and path to property file is correct (even if relative to classpath).

Keep your eyes on logs and don't ignore any exception.