# Inject value from properties into interface field

Tags: java, spring, interface, static, code-injection

Is there an option to insert property on interface field? I tried something like this, but it didn't work.

```
public interface ServicePathsConfig {
    @Value("${default-connection-timeout}")
    int DEFAULT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT = 1000;
}
```

I tried to make default setter with @PostConstruct, same result. Any ideas how can I inject property to interface field?

Comment: You cannot inject into an interface field. "fields" in interfaces are actually `public static final` and you cannot use `@Value` on a `static` field.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring: How to inject a value to static field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253694/spring-how-to-inject-a-value-to-static-field)

Answer (score 0):

You can open config java class with this codes.
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.??")
@PropertySource("classpath:(??.properties"))

And put default-connection-tiemout to another new property file without int.
But you cant inject this to interface you need to inject some java class.

Comment: Any idea how i can create this? default methods didnt work too

Answer (score 0):

```
java class:

@Component
public class blabla implements blabla1 {

    @Value("${default-connection.timeout}")
   int default-connection;

--------------
interface
public interface blabla1 {
}

-------------
file:
Timeout.properties
default-connection.timeout=1000

------------------
java class:

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.(your package name)")
@PropertySource("classpath:connection.properties")
public class TimeoutConfig {


}
```

Comment: @NOXYEES you can check that

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, in some cases you can turn your interface into an abstract class, and then it is possible:

```java
public abstract class ServicePathsConfig {
    @Value("${default-connection-timeout:1000}")
    protected int defaultConnectTimeout;

    public abstract void someMethod();
}
```